# Trigonometric re-write I don't understand

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\int \sin^3{x}\,\cos^5{x}\,dx = \int \sin{x}\,(\cos^5{x}-\cos^7{x})\,dx$$

My ignorance amuses me hehe. Even if I multiply it out I still don't get it.

Comment: How about $\sin^2 x = 1 -\cos^2 x$.

Comment: Try to use $\sin^2 x = 1- \cos^2 x$...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\sin^3x\,\cos^5x=\sin x\,\sin^2x\,\cos^5x=\sin x\,(1-\cos^2x)\,\cos^5x=\sin x\,(\cos^5x-\cos^7x)$.

Comment: +1, of course. I took the liberty of inserting some spacing characters to make the formulas a bit better readable.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks.  I'd noticed it looked funny, but didn't think to put in the `\,`.